# intersection of a parabolic subgroup with a subgroup

Tags: algebraic-groups

I'm interested in the following question: let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero (just for simplicity), $G$ a connected semi-simple $k$-group, $P\subsetneq G$ a parabolic $k$-subgroup, and $H\subsetneq G$ a connected $k$-subgroup. Assume that $H\nsubseteq P$, then does the intersection $H\cap P$ becomes a parabolic $k$-subgroup for $H$? One might even assume that $H$ is reductive.

Comment: This is true precisely when the $H$-orbit of the base point of $G/P$ is closed which is usually not the case. (If it is the case for all conjugates of a given $P$ then all the $H$-orbits are closed which is *very* rarely the case.

Comment: What Torsten points out is true but of course hard to test even if the field is algebraically closed.  The problem with arbitrary closed subgroups `$H$` (reductive or not) is that they can be extremely small relative to `$G$` and not well-placed in terms of Lie-theoretic structure.  Think of `$G$` as a huge special linear group, for instance.   In other words, your question is too loosely formulated to have an interesting answer.